# Why didn’t Bud White attack Exley for being sarcastic in this situation?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

While Exley was standing at a distance in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Bud White found the body of his close
friend and colleague Dick Stensland under a white sheet at the mortuary:

> EXLEY: **Hell of a way to avoid a prison sentence**.
>
> Bud White: You tell me what happened?
>
> Exley: Appears three men held up a coffee shop. The guy at the
> register pulled a .38, so they killed him.

Exley’s comment here sounds like a sarcastic remark about the extreme
and  undesirable nature of Dick Stensland’s death as a way to avoid
going to prison.

Why didn’t Bud White attack Exley for being sarcastic in this situation?